# ThreadPoolExecutor sharing the same blocking queue

Tags: java

I have a scenario where two threadPool instances sharing the same blocking queue. Here is the code

```
<bean id="TaskQueue" class="java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue">
        <constructor-arg type="int">
            <value>1000</value>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>

    <bean id="TaskThreadPool1" class="java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor">
        <constructor-arg type="int">
            <value>10</value>
        </constructor-arg>
        <constructor-arg type="int">
            <value>50</value>
        </constructor-arg>
        <constructor-arg type="long">
            <value>5</value>
        </constructor-arg>
        <constructor-arg>
            <value>SECONDS</value>
        </constructor-arg>
        <constructor-arg>
            <ref bean="TaskQueue" />
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>


    <bean id="TaskThreadPool2" class="java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor">
        <constructor-arg type="int">
            <value>1</value>
        </constructor-arg>
        <constructor-arg type="int">
            <value>1</value>
        </constructor-arg>
        <constructor-arg type="long">
            <value>5</value>
        </constructor-arg>
        <constructor-arg>
            <value>SECONDS</value>
        </constructor-arg>
        <constructor-arg>
            <ref bean="TaskQueue" />
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>
```

Now I have a question, what would be behaviour if I will submit more than 5 task in TaskThreadPool2 through TaskThreadPool2.execute(task) .

What i feel the TaskThreadPool1 should also start executing these task bcoz it is also listening to same queue.

Answer (score 0):

Really can't think of reason having two thread pools for same blocking queue. Best way of find out is making a program and run it.

Having said that no need to have two such pools, increase the size of pool to double.

Also, if you want to have two pools, then check for concurrency because there might be scenarios where one threads from both pool will try to access same resource in queue. This can result in unpredictable results.

Answer (score 0):

No, TaskThreadPool1 will not execute tasks from queue, see ThreadPoolExecutor constructor (source) - it does not start listening to the working queue. You can easily test it:

```
    BlockingQueue<Runnable> q = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>();
    Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("running");
        }
    };
    q.add(r);
    q.add(r);
    ThreadPoolExecutor ex1 = new ThreadPoolExecutor(10, 50, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS, q);
```

Run it, nothing happens, ex1 ignores tasks in queue. But add this

```
    ex1.execute(r);
```

And you will see

```
    running
    running
    running
```

Executor was activated with execute().

Comment: thats not true. it is happening bcoz, execute method was not called on one of the threadPool. once you call the execute method, it will start the worker thread and then it will start listening. then we will have two pools listening to the same queue and we will get ubiquitous response.